# how to save many objects in a $session array variable

Tags: php, session, object

I'm new in the object oriented programming so this question might be silly...

I've created my class in a separate file called classProduct.php

```
<?php
class  product{

    public $prodId;
    public $prodName;
    public $prodPrice;

    public function __construct($prodId,$prodName,$prodPrice){
        $this->prodId = $prodId;
        $this->prodName=$prodName;
        $this->prodPrice=$prodPrice;
    }

    public function get_prodId(){
        return $this->prodId;
    }

    public function get_prodName(){
        return $this->prodName;
    }

    public function get_prodPrice(){
        return $this->prodPrice;
    }
}
?>
```

Then I tried to create a new object in a $_SESSION variable. This happens in another file called dailySales.php where I include the previous file using:

```
include_once("classProduct.php");
```

What I want to do is to save in `$_SESSION['myItems']` each new object. I am trying something like:

```
$newItem= new product($var,$var,$var);
$_SESSION['myItems']=array($newItem); // I believe here is where I do it wrong
```

Every time the buyer chooses one more products, the pages reloads (with ajax). When I `echo` or `var_dump` the `$_SESSION['myItems']` I only get the last object. What do I need to change to get it working correctly?

Of course I do need the object so I can easily remove a product from the shopping cart if
'Delete' is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me locally.

Define your items session variable as an array, then push them into the variable using `array_push`

```
class product {

  public $prodId;
  public $prodName;
  public $prodPrice;

  public function __construct($prodId, $prodName, $prodPrice) {
    $this->prodId    = $prodId;
    $this->prodName  = $prodName;
    $this->prodPrice = $prodPrice;
  }

  public function get_prodId() {
    return $this->prodId;
  }

  public function get_prodName() {
    return $this->prodName;
  }

  public function get_prodPrice() {
    return $this->prodPrice;
  }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
$product = new product(1, "test", 23);
$product2 = new product(2, "test2", 43);

$_SESSION['items'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['items'], $product, $product2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['items']);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the output of `print_r()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => product Object
        (
            [prodId] => 1
            [prodName] => test
            [prodPrice] => 23
        )
[1] => product Object
    (
        [prodId] => 2
        [prodName] => test2
        [prodPrice] => 43
    )

)
```

Comment: nope that is not want i want... i want the name of the variable that stores the objects to be the same ... i want it to increase automatically not manually..also plz provide all the code cause i dont see what u pass in print_r , and i dont see where u use array_push..

Comment: You don't have to do this manually, this is just an example. Also, you have to scroll down in the first code block to see the rest of the code. I will look into it the name as a reference